# In an ios cordova plugin, for a view controller, how to know for sure if an orientation change should happen

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins

I implement my own view controller extending UIViewController inside a cordova plugin and I want it to rotate only if cordova allows it in

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation
```

in MainViewController.m.

code:

```
@implementation MyViewController
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
    return YES/NO???????;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use one of the specific plugins for that issue. Two quick options:

1. https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-orientation
2. https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation

Comment: Do you have access to your main view controller?

Comment: for cordova's main webview:
    webview.window.rootViewController?

Answer (score 0):

`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` **is not for cordova/phonegap application** That can be used for native applications.

Try following links :

1. https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
2. http://www.web-garden.co.uk/blog/2012/7/29/how-to-control-the-page-orientations-in-your-ios-phonegap-application-part-2

Following function is used for native applications.

BEFORE iOS 6

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        // your code for portrait mode
    }
    return YES;
}
```

AFTER iOS 6

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
      UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
      if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
          // your code for portrait mode
      }
      return YES;
 }
```

Comment: so how should i know in a plugin if orientation should be changed?

Comment: check the first URL you will get option to check screen orientation

Answer (score 0):

You can get the cordova supported orientations inside a plugin using:

```
self.viewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations
```

So you can do this

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
    return [self.viewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:interfaceOrientation]];
}
```

Comment: supportedInterfaceOrientations is NSUInteger